# How to ignore the next X tokens in antlr?

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to model a language using the ANLTR syntax. A feature is "the next X parameters can be defaulted". Syntactically, it looks like the following:
Consider a

```
f(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5)
```

f is a function with 5 parameters a, b, c, d and e with respectively the default values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. The language allows the user to "default the next X parameters" by specifying like so:

```
f(2, 3#, 10)
```

Function f here is called with a=2, b/c/d=default and e=10. As such, it is equivalent to

```
f(2, 2, 3, 4, 10)
```

Is there a feature in ANTLR4 where I can "skip the next X parser tree elements"? The syntactical ANTRL4 model would look something like

```
INT: [0-9]+;
DEFAULT: INT'*';
STRING; // shortened

parameter: INT | DEFAULT_VALUE ((INT | DEFAULT_VALUE) ',')*
functionCall: STRING '(' parameter* ')'
```

When I'm parsing the functionCall tokens, I'd like to parse the value of DEFAULT_VALUE and then simply skip parsing the next DEFAULT_VALUE.INT() tokens.

The resulting tree then would look something like

- functioncall

  - parameter1 (2)
  - parameter5 (10)

instead of

- functioncall

  - parameter1 (2)
  - DEFAULT_VALUE(3)
  - parameter5 (10)

or

- functioncall

  - parameter1 (2)
  - parameter2 (2)
  - parameter3 (3)
  - parameter4 (4)
  - parameter5 (10)

Another solution is to simply model the DEFAULT_VALUE. In the parser tree, I can then just ignore the next function parameters. However, this solution will lead to an enormous amount of extra code in the conversion from the parser tree model into the object model.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate function for that. You can simply ignore the child nodes of a given context by not visiting them. It's up to you how you walk the parse tree.

Comment: Said differently: I'd like the resulting parse tree to not contain DEFAULT_VALUE and null values for `b`, `c` and `d` to be null. I am aware it's possible to model the DEFAULT_VALUE, and simply consume it in the code using the parse tree. Having DEFAULT_VALUE in the consumer code makes the consumer code really, really messy (because of the many functions the language has).